# IAPWS-IF97 empirical equations for water and steam

Tags: water, density, viscosity, thermal-conductivity

IAPWS-IF97 provides empirical equation the dynamic viscosity and the thermal conductivity for water, are there any formulas by IAPWS-IF97 for the density and the specific heat capacity of water?

I found "some" empirical formulas for both, the density and the specific heat capacity of water by going through some papers, but I wonder about recommendations by the IAPWS-IF97 if there is any.

Do you have any recommendation for similar equation for steam?

Comment: How accurate do you need to be? Have you considered using "steam tables" or an equation of state?

Comment: @electronpusher I would like to avoid using tables just to make everything $T$ or $P$ or both dependent; in terms of the accuracy, I would like to get "close" to the IAPWS-IF97 values in the region 0 - 150 °C and up to 1 MPa, where the standard EoS may already fail (still even up to 0.4, 0.5 MPa it won't be that accurate). Recently, I found some formula for $C_P$, but I cannot find any for the isochoric heat capacity, and there is no direct (constant) relation to obtain the other from knowing the $C_P$, e.g. Mayer.

Comment: I'm guessing the [generalization of Meyer's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relations_between_heat_capacities?wprov=sfla1) is no good without an equation of state. I'm not sure what your options are if theoretical models (EoS) aren't sufficient and you don't want to use tabulated empirical data.

Comment: I was also not sure and that's why I asked :), but it's fine, alternatively I can just search though the tables.